# How to change dimensions of np.array for greyscale images

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have the following code to load an image:

```py
img = imread(os.path.join('./Faces/','10.png')) 
print(img.shape)
img = np.mean(img, axis=2)
img = img.astype(int)
print(img.shape)
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
(200, 180, 3)
(200, 180)
```

I understand that I'm averaging out the RGB layers into a greyscale value, but I have my Keras input layer defined with shape `(200, 280, 1)`.  Is there a way to have the shape changed to this? Is there even a functional difference between having a matrix of the two shapes as outputted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't average out the channels. There's a particular balance between the RGB channels to transform a picture to grayscale, and it's not conveniently 0.33% each. It's that:

```
((0.3*R) + (0.59*G) + (0.11*B))
```

Instead of averaging or doing it manually, I suggest that you use:

```
import cv2 

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Then add a dimension:

```
img = img[..., np.newaxis]
```

or

```
img = np.expand_dims(img, -1)
```

The functional difference is that obviously, your CNN will not see color if you turn it into grayscale. So it won't be able to use this information to classify.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  it's all about the structure, less about the colors, so it's perfectly fine to lose the colors in my case.  didn't know about the specific greyscale balances you mentioned.  good to have that pointed out.  merci!

Comment: Glad I could help. I see you have accepted the other answer but I hope you will consider converting the color images to grayscale the proper way. You really shouldn't just sum up the channels.

Comment: That's exactly how i do it now, indeed

Comment: Nicolas, I accepted both answers (yours first, then the other).  But didn't know there's only one "accepted" answer, hence yours was "unaccepted", now I see

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `expand_dims` function in numpy (see [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)).

It works as follows in your case:

```
img = img.astype(int)
print(img.shape)
# Prints (100, 100)

img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
print(img.shape)
# Prints (100, 100, 1)
```